# Date format in float from Persavise db

Tags: php, btrieve

I got data from a Persavive V12 Db. The dates are in a weird format. 
They are like float :

```
Example of date in table : 39787.0
```

Do someone know this kind of format ? It seems to be the number of days from 1901-01-01.

Since the dates are float, is it possible to add days from a date in PHP ? Like :

```
$from = '1901-01-01';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from .' +'. $float .' days'));
```

I got always 1970-01-01. Is there another way ?

Comment: strtotime will output a unix timestamp meaning the first day posible is 1970 01 01
what is the solfware writing this date ? Maybe we can search what is the date format.

Comment: Is the field in the Pervasive database marked as Float in the DDFs?  Pervasive has had a Date field for many years and it's not a Float.  .  Is this from an application you developed or third party?  Have you contacted the vendor of the app to find out the date format?

Comment: Unlucky I don't have access to the DB know, just got data from the db but no DDF. I will try to find the date format in my Pervasive server local.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer so don't hurt me much.
I'm not quite sure what you want to do (put back in the database or perform further operations so I only posted one solution)

The number you posted 39787.0 is a unix timestamp.  You need to use *mktime* to convert what you want to a number (And you need *date* to convert it to a readable form).  Since mktime uses 1901-01-01 as a starting date as well you have to make a couple of changes.

I was a biz lazy and didn't include all the code for all fields but this should allow you modify to add whatever you want (and possibly clean it up to a single line if you want).
I made it in long form so it's easy to read.

```
    <?

    $olddate = 39787.0;
    $hour = 0;
    $min =  0;
    $sec =  0;
    $month =  0;
    $year = 0;
    $day = 12;
    $month += date("m",$olddate);
    $day += date("d",$olddate);
    $year += date("Y",$olddate);
    $x = date("Ymd",mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$month,$day,$year));
    echo $x;

    ?>
```

Comment: It's not an Unix Timestamp. Since timestamp are more like `1470943987`. And if it was, you just have to use date('d-m-Y', $timestamp), no need of mktime.

Answer (score 0):

If 39787.0 is in the database, what value is that in a real date (using the application)?  If it's 2008-12-05, the it's a VB Date.  Do you know what the application was written in? I've seen people use the VB Date data type and store it in an 8 byte float in Btrieve (back in 2003).  If it's a VB Date, 1 is `1899-12-31`.  You should be able to add the number to `1899-12-30` to get the correct date value.  Something like:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('1899-12-30');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P39787D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```